# how to know programmatically which view is presently appears on screen while using navigation controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

i want to know which view controller is on top of screen at a particular time so that i can control that views...

i have a 2 buttons on my bottom navigation bar,and one of these buttons pressed i should have to load particular view and and these buttons will appear in all views ...

i am pushing visit view whenever i press visit button ,but when i press visit button in visit view is gets pushing new view on existing visit view ,so whenever i press back is not getting me to previous view suddenly ...

so i want to eliminate these condition

Comment: are you using the navigation controller? I ask because you said the buttons were on the bottom so I wasn't sure

Comment: yes ,i am using navigation controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time parsing that question, but it sounds to me as though you might be looking for the [`topViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController) and [`visibleViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/visibleViewController) properties of [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).